# Скачивание файла через request Node.JS

Tags: node.js, request

В общем, мне нужно скачать .dat файл с майнкрафт хостинга и обработать его, получить информацию о инвентаре игрока. Код для обработки я уже сделал, он полностью работает, но со скачиванием файла возникли проблемы.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const nbt = require('nbt');
const request = require('request');

const link = "https://aternos.org/ajax/server/files/download?file=%2Fworld%2Fplayerdata%2F14fbb6b1-85aa-3c9e-ba25-6b919ad805d1.dat";
const cookie = "тут кукисы";

request({
    url: link,
    method: "GET",

    headers: {
        'set-cookie': cookie,
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0",
        'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        'Accept-Language': "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1",
        'Connection': "keep-alive",
        'content-type': 'application/gzip',
    }
})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('14fbb6b1-85aa-3c9e-ba25-6b919ad805d1.dat'));
```

Я в headers накидал и нужного и ненужного, так, на всякий случай, но мне это не помогло. Файл как бы скачивается, но он отличается от того который я скачиваю вручную, и этот файл невозможно обработать. В чём может быть проблема?